# Wait for Javascript load from CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cdn

I have this block of javascript in a Rails app, with turbo-link enabled:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/be7019ee387/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var ready = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#table-products').dataTable();
    }, 100);
    };
    $(document).on('ready, page:change', ready);    
</script>
```

Usually, I get the error that the .dataTable() function is undefined, and a refresh can solve the problem. However, refresh is not always pleasant, so I added the setTimeout for 100ms to wait for the js from CDN to load.

So far I don't see any issue in my dev environment, but I am afraid that if there is a slow client, the js won't finish loading within 100ms.
I wonder if there would be a better way to solve this, like checking if the two js files have been loaded, similar to $(document).ready for DOM.

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't really make sense, browser should compile the script tags in order, regardless of source. You should read the `ready` docs though, you are using `on('ready'` which is discouraged in the docs and is deprecated.  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a [gem for this](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails). It's really easy to use and comes with bootstrap styling options. This is more elegant than what you have because it doesn't rely on CDNs and instead leverages the Rails asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/be7019ee387/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.holdReady(true);
var s = setInterval(function() {
  if ($.fn.hasOwnProperty("DataTable") 
      && typeof $.fn.DataTable === "function") {
        $.holdReady(false);
        clearInterval(s);
  };
 }, 1); 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table-products").dataTable();
});  
</script>
</head>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/RZVRL/

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way I can find is to move all the cdn links to the layout page in the , so that all the libraries will be loaded and cached for the entire user experience.